# How to get a fixed picture in the field without affect by responsive effect?

Tags: views, theming, entities, ubercart, media

I want to get this picture fixed on original size. Please refer to this picture. There is a picture showing up a drill. I want to make it keep on 100x59px. When I adjust the browser's window, the responsive effect is that I want but the picture will shrink its width. Here is the [webpage](http://www.jeffhost.idv.tw/online-buying). I also use this command:`grep -inR image-style-cu-product-list /mydrupalcssdirectory`. I can't figure out why I did't get this specific CSS? Are there any methods to keep this picture fixed on 100x59px. (At least I want the width able to be fixed.) The solving method is not limit in CSS. Wish a help. Thanks.

[image: The picture showing up the matter.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables are by definition "responsive" (quotes intended), meaning they will give more space to the more "filled" cell. You need to tell the browser to reserve a certain amount of space for the cell with the following css:

```
.views-field-uc-product-image {
  min-width: 110px;
  max-width: 110px;
}
```

The extra 10 pixels are to account for the padding around the image. The `max-width: 110px` is added to ensure the cell will also not take more space then needed.

Comment: Hi, it works. I enable my theme's custom css and then I write the code. Perfect!!!